# How do I configure the jetty http client over JAXRS to connect to a unix domain socket?

Tags: jax-rs, jetty, unix-socket

I have the following code to connect to a JAXRS endpoint using jersey and the jetty HTTP client as follows:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.connectorProvider(new JettyConnectorProvider());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget xxxTarget = client.target(xxxUrl);
```

The server running the service being connected to is bound to a UNIX domain docket.

What URL format do I use to connect to a service above?

```
String xxxUrl = "unix:[what-goes-here?]";
```